# bower init reference error parent is not definined

Tags: npm, bower

I am just starting to familiarize myself with bower.
I just installed bower version 1.3.12.
I checked my node version 0.10.29

When i ran bower init I received a question mark with the name of the folder?  I assume this is the default so i clicked error and the command line returned 
ReferenceError: parent is not defined.

So I retyped the name of my directory open-weather-map thinking that I just need to retype the default but I am still getting parent is not defined.

I did not see an answer on the Bower docs so I am assuming this should be a straight forward fix.

I there an additional step I skipped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's coused by Rx https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/434
Looks like we need to wait til this issue will get a fix.

Comment: You were so right on this one.  The error was fixed.  Reinstalled it just now and everything was fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue this morning - was caused by a new Rx release.

To fix I re-installed node and bower (which brought through the patched Rx version):

```
$ npm uninstall bower -g
$ brew uninstall node
$ brew install node
$ npm install bower -g
```

Might be the nuclear option, but fixed it for me.

For more info on the patch see [here](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/434).

Answer (score 0):

bower init would have created a bower.json file in the local director. Try removing this and running bower init again. Also you could try running `bower init --allow-root`

Comment: Still getting the same response:   ?name: (name of dir)  I am looking at the configuration but not seeing what I am doing wrong

Comment: I'm struggling with same problem on Windows :| `--allow-root` didn't work for me.
`Node: v0.10.33
Bower: 1.3.12`

Comment: Looks like they just had to fix the bug.  Did the same reinstall just now and everything worked.  Thanks for your help.